# Center a window horizontally only

Tags: windows-7, window

I'm looking for a positioning tool with an option to center any window horizontally only (i.e. without changing the vertical position).

[Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/) is good, but doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

http://milesaheadsoftware.tk/

MoveIt includes the option. A great tool.